# Dispay marker on Current position at map using sencha touch2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am able to display map on screen and get the current positions of latitude and longitude. However I want to display a marker at the position of those latitude and longitude values. I have tried by adding a listener when map is rendered. Below is the code. But no marker shows up on the screen. Any pointers on how to get the marker displayed at the current position will be really helpful..

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<link href="touch/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
```

Ext.application({
    name: 'MapApp',

```
launch: function() {
var lat,lng;

//get latitude and longititude values

Ext.device.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
success: function(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;

    lng = position.coords.longitude;
    alert(lat);
    alert(lng);
     Ext.Viewport.add( {
        xtype:'map',
        useCurrentLocation:true,
        fullscreen: true,
        layout:'fit',
        listeners : {
        maprender : function() {
            alert('map rendered');
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            title : 'testing',

            });
        }
    }

    });
},
failure: function() {
    alert('something went wrong!');
}
```

Comment: you need to put map key inside marker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
maprender : function(map, gmap, options) {
            alert('map rendered');
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                title : 'testing',
                map: //gmap or map, try both one of them will work
            });
            }
```

this map key is importatnt also u need to ensure you sabe markers in a array for future use